# Python plot with multindex

Tags: python, indexing, bar-chart, series

I have the follwing series with a multindex (Date, Risk). Where Date goes from 2007-2010 and Risk can have 1-4 values.

```
Date  Risk    Value
2007     1    10
         3    5
         4    20
2008     1    3
         2    3
         3    10
         4    6
         5    15
```

I would like to plot a barplot but using 4 different colors for each risk. The x axis should be the year and the y-axis Value.
Thanks